# ios how to load the local photos use mwphotobrowser.

Tags: ios, view, collections, local, photo

i had downloaded an sample code  that used mwphotobrowser,it's really cool.but i have problem when i try to use it,i want it could load the local photos instead URL. i tried again and again, but failed...here is the code below:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "MWPhotoBrowser.h"
#import "Image.h"
#import "ImageCell.h"

@interface DEMOSevenViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, MWPhotoBrowserDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *browserImages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MWPhotoBrowser *browser;

@end

@implementation DEMOSevenViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}    

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
self.browser.displayActionButton = YES;
self.browser.displayNavArrows = YES;
self.browser.displaySelectionButtons = NO;
self.browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES;
self.browser.alwaysShowControls = YES;
self.browser.enableGrid = NO;
self.browser.startOnGrid = NO;
self.browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

[self.browser showNextPhotoAnimated:YES];
[self.browser showPreviousPhotoAnimated:YES];

[self loadImages];
}

- (void)loadImages
{
self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.browserImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", HOST_URL, @"All_Images.php"]];
NSData *jsonResults = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResults options:0 error:NULL];

NSDictionary *images = results[@"Images"];
for (NSDictionary *img in images) {
    Image *imageObj = [[Image alloc] init];
    imageObj.imageId = [img objectForKey:@"id"];
    imageObj.imageName = [img objectForKey:@"name"];

    // Get the full image path
    NSString *fullImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", HOST_URL, [img objectForKey:@"full_image"]];
    imageObj.imagePath = fullImagePath;

    // Get the thumbnail image path depending on the device
    NSString *thumbnailPath;
    if (DEVICE_IS_PAD) {
        thumbnailPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", HOST_URL, [img objectForKey:@"thumbnail_ipad"]];
    } else {
        thumbnailPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", HOST_URL, [img objectForKey:@"thumbnail_iphone"]];
    }
    imageObj.imageThumbnail = thumbnailPath;

    // Creates an object for each image and fill it with the retrieved info
    [self.images addObject:imageObj];

    // This array stores the image paths for later use (displaying them in a photo browser)
    MWPhoto *browserImage = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:imageObj.imagePath]];
    browserImage.caption = imageObj.imageName;
    [self.browserImages addObject:browserImage];
}
[self.collectionView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - MWPhotoBrowserDelegate
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser
{
NSLog(@"Count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.browserImages.count);
return self.browserImages.count;
//    return 93;
}

- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
NSLog(@"Index: %lu", (unsigned long)index);
if (index < self.browserImages.count) {
    return self.browserImages[index];
}
return nil;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.images.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Image *image = self.images[indexPath.row];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image.imageThumbnail] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Opens the image browser
//    NSLog(@"Selected Index: %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
[self.browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.browser animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

i am really need help about it ,please please please help me.thank you very much .[it's the sample code from the cool man](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp6a67f83l0rzin/PhotoBrowserTest.zip)

Comment: Just create the `NSURL` with a local file path using `NSURL fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: thank you very very much, please .show me how to creat it .i am a novice.

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate function:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
return [photoShowArray count];
```

}

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
return [photoShowArray count];
```

}

```
-(id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
return [photoShowArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

}

```
-(id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
return [thumbnailsArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

}

and use the [MWPhoto photoWithUrl:]to load your image as it has cache.
you can convert the local path to url with [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]

Answer (score 0):

Print your image path and try to open it in browser

Comment: thanks very very much, but i can't understand and the local file path,it's difficult to me.